Passing a javascript method as an argument
I've been around javascript for a long time, but am pretty rusty with javascript Classes. For a particular project I'm working on, things are starting to get unwieldy and I'd like to start cutting up my code into separate files. I don't want to have to import all my functions explicitly, so I've started wrapping them up into a Class (which makes sense for other reasons also). Some of my functions return callbacks (functions). That is:
return functionName;

Which I can use like:
var callBack = functionReturningFunction();
...
callBack();

I cannot find any information about returning and passing methods, rather than functions what is the syntax there? Ideally I'd like to pass in methods as arguments to the constructor so I can say:
const myObject = new MyClass(methodName);

So I don't have to do:
const myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.methodName();


The question is ambiguous. You want to use classes but you don't want to use them how the classes are used, you want to use them in a different way. Which way?

Classes and methods in JavaScript are syntactic sugar. A method is a function that is associated to an object (the prototype of the class) but the function itself is standalone, it does not know anything about the class that considers the function as one of its "method". By changing the classes prototypes, the same function can be associated as "method" to multiple classes.

"I'd like to pass in methods as arguments to the constructor" - that doesn't make much sense to me. Maybe what you're looking for is dropping the const myObject and just calling new MyClass().methodName();?

"I don't want to have to import all my functions explicitly" - maybe what you're actually looking for are namespace imports, import * as myModule from '…'; myModule.someFunction()? Do not use classes if you're not actually going to instantiate them multiple times with different arguments.

"I've been around javascript for a long time" - are you still familiar with .prototype methods then?

@axiac I think this is less true than it used to be, now that javascript classes have private properties. I do want to use classes as classes.

@Bergi I'm not hugely familiar with the whole .prototype javascript paradigm/pattern. I understand that you can extend the prototype of javascript Classes but I've avoided doing it as to do so apparently is "poor practice". I have used javascript in a more generic way as a procedural language.

@iPadDeveloper2011 So you've never created your own classes with function constructors and created .prototype methods on them? Maybe you should start learning about that first before using class syntax. Either way, if you want to keep a procedural approach and not rewrite everything as OOP, you can still use modules purely for namespacing and scoping.

@iPadDeveloper2011 " I'm not hugely familiar with the whole .prototype javascript paradigm/pattern" - this is kind of the thing everyone is pointing at - classes are just some sugar on top of the prototype system in JS. Private variables are equivalent to instantiating a function within a closure, etc... Todays problem is that nobody knows the underlying stuff anymore. Most devs only know React these days, which isn't even that.

@somethinghere. Yes, for me its that I've worked with too many other languages (Java, c, c++, c#, pascal, fortran, basic, PHP, ...) I try to steer away from language specific quirks.  I can mostly avoid javascript idiosyncrasies, but every so often they are important and trip me up.

I didn't downvote the question but it is not clear. You say "so I don't have to do" but you do not say how you want to do. What is your question, more precisely?

@iPadDeveloper2011 Your answer to the question tells me that this is an XY problem. You ask a technical question to complete a solution to the real problem. Ask instead about the real problem that you want to solve. That problem is not about JavaScript, it is probably about a design pattern. Step back and describe what do you want to achieve, explain how you reached this technical solution. The solution to the real problem is very different than what you have now and, probably, much cleaner.

@iPadDeveloper2011 Having an initialisation method that must be called after construction (or otherwise the instance stays unusable) is an antipattern in OOP. Better use different static methods that do initialisation work and then construct and return full instances. But really you'll need to [edit] your question with some concrete code, your current snippets are rather unclear.

@Bergi I'm asking a general question, rather than about my specific issue, so I think it is OK as is. Specifically, I'm creating an infinite 3D world using perlin noise. The object is a single rectangular terrain 'tile' in that world. The Perlin noise gets a bit sameold after a while, so each tile has further customizations.  I have a 'volcanoIslands' tile and a 'desertOasis' tile etc.  Normally I just want a random tile so I'll probably just select a random tile in my constructor. Still, it would be nice to be able to specify a particular tile. Asking specifically would change the question.

@iPadDeveloper2011 More concrete code, not necessarily a concrete use case. I still don't get what passing a tile type has to do with "pass in methods as arguments to the constructor"

@Bergi I had a detailed comment, but then I got a phone call... lost it. Think craterLakes(), volcanoIslands(), desertOasis() ... if you spend 3 minutes thinking about it all will be clear. It all seems good to me: a direct, clear, well motivated question about something I'd forgotten, a couple of helpful answers... I can't see a problem. Feel free to upvote my question and answer. Thanks.

@iPadDeveloper2011 It's not clear at all how you wrote those methods. Of course I know how I would design them, but I don't even know what properties your tiles have! Please don't write a comment but [edit] your question.

@Bergi. Its just that I don't really get what you want me to do.  My question is not about terrain tiles. It's about passing methods. Including specific details that don't pertain to the question is surely not helpful. If I start doing that, just where do I stop!? Besides, the question already has 2 good answers. Thanks for your help with that.

Just basic info for you:

I don't want to have to import all my functions explicitly

You don't need a class. Instead, you can use NamesSpaces
You can create file helper.js:
export function one() {}
export function two() {}
export function three() {}

and then basicly include them from:
import * as Helper from "./helper.js"
Helper.one()
Helper.two()
Helper.three()


If you like Classes, then you should know about "static" feature.

export class Helper {
  static one() {}
  static two() {}
  static three() {}
}

and then ...
import { Helper } from "./helper.js"
Helper.one()
Helper.two()
Helper.three()

Good Luck with your project! ;-)

"If you like Classes and want to create new isntance, then you should know about "static" feature" - that doesn't make sense. The code with static methods does not create a new instance, and even in your first bullet point you said that classes should not be used when needing only a namespace.

I have a feeling that English is not Konstantin's main language. I think there are helpful things in his answer. I will edit to improve.

Static properties are not OOP. The class is just a global object, nothing more, and it acts like a namespace. Its methods are global functions with longer names.

The stackoverflow fairy brought me the answer as I was finishing typing out the question. Following the pattern in my question, I have:
return this.methodName;

Which I can use like:
var callBack = myObject.methodReturningMethod();
...
callBack();

From outside my Class. Importantly I should have:
methodReturningMethod(){
 ...
 return this.aMethod.bind(this);
}

inside methodReturningMethod() if aMethod() accesses any object properties because javascript is * special * like that (and will get all confused if I don't).
Inside class methods I can have stuff like:
this.callBackMethod = this.methodReturningMethod();
...
this.callBackMethod();

which will call whichever method this.methodReturningMethod() returns.
I don't think its possible to specify an object method as a parameter to that object's constructor because object methods don't exist before the object has been constructed. Shout out if you know a way. After the object has been created I can do things like:
myObject.methodReceivingMethod(myObject.method);


Obviously, LMK if I've got something wrong here. It concerns me a bit that the callBack() is "detached" from the object.

Yes, a detached method typically won't work as a callback

@Bergi OMG I'm always tripping over the whole javascript this, self, .bind(this) issue. Its very anti-intuitive to me.

@Bergi Right, so if callBack() refers to object properties, it might get lost because the context of this might have changed. A solution would be to bind this to methodName inside methodReturningMethod? Can I do: return this.methodName.bind(this)? If so, I will update the answer.

Yes, that, or return an arrow function

Great, thanks so much for your help. I've updated the answer.

What is the benefit of this approach?

@axiac Its just how to pass methods around. Helpful if you're moving from procedural code to OO.

That is not OOP. That is still procedural coding (and habits), complicated using classes. In OOP, one creates an object (as an instance of a class) then tells it to do something (and usually pass some data to it). One tells the object what to do, not how to do it.

Umm. @axiac yes, I think I get that thanks. In my actual code I don't have methodReturningMethod() etc. of course. I just have that in my answer for clarity. In my code I'm interested in doing things like: tile = new Terrain(volcanoIslands); I didn't want to put my code in the question/answer because I felt it unnecessarily complicated things.
